# Box86 can't find some specific libraries

Tags: libraries, arm, steam, emulation

I am trying to run some programs on an Ubuntu ARM64 machine with Box86 (in this case, Steam).
While starting up it crashes, and I noticed in the console the following errors:

```
Error loading needed lib libgailutil.so.18
Error loading one of needed lib
Error loading needed lib libatk-bridge.so
Warning: Cannot dlopen("libatk-bridge.so"/0x6e2a7550, 1)
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
```

Note that I have already installed those libraries (tried both arm64 and armhf architectures).

I have also ensured that Box86 was loading the libraies from the correct directories by adding this in the in the Steam script in `/usr/local/bin` before the executable: `BOX86_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf [steam path] [flags]`

I also made sure to check that the `.so` files were in there, before trying this. (For example, the complete path for `libgailutil.so.18` is `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgailutil.so.18`)
All of this also aplies to `libatk-bridge`.

Am I doing something wrong?
All help is appreciated.